# How do you put two things in a "javascript:alert(?

Tags: javascript, html, function, submit, alert

```
<body>
<script>
var monster = 40
</script>


<p>Type 'Spark' to Attack.</p>
<form action="javascript:alert( 'Enemy has monster Health!' );"
>
  <div>
    <input type="text">
    <input type="submit">
  </div>
</form>
<span></span>

<script>

$( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
  if ( $( "input:first" ).val() === "correct" ) {
    $( "span" ).text( "Validated..." ).show();
    return;
  }

  $( "span" ).text( "Not valid!" ).show().fadeOut( 1000 );
  event.preventDefault();
});
</body>
```

This is my code so far everything works great except at the top when I try to use the javascript:alert( I can only either type (monster) which gives me 40 or ("The enemies health is monster!") What I would like to do is have it say the The Enemies health is what ever the variable Monster =

so for example they type spark to attack then I say - 5 monster health is 35 no problem only problem is I want the words and variable in the same sentence? So it can say the enemy health is 35 not monster.

Answer (score 1):

You have to perform string concatenation.

```
alert('Enemy has ' + monster + ' Health!');
```

Answer (score -2):

JavaScript is not strongly typed.  Convert  monster to a string explicitly then concatenate to your message.

Comment: you should add an example code line to show what you mean

Comment: There's no need to explicitly convert to a string.  See the answer by plalx.